# data.table: How can I indicate which variables to use when the variable names are stored into objects?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to reshape my data set using `data.table`. I have two variables storing the column names of the variables of interest

```
by_var = "treatment"
mean_var = "decrease"
```

Here are some data:

```
dat = as.data.table(OrchardSprays)
```

and I would like to perform the following operation

```
dat[,list(mean=mean(decrease)),by=treatment]
```

**How can I indicate which variables to use when the variable names are stored into objects?** I am trying to do something like that

```
dat[,list(mean=mean(mean_var)),by=by_var]
```

When doing so, `by_var` seem to work fine but `mean_var` is not considered as a column name.

Comment: You can do `by=byvar`, as you have it. For `mean_var`, you'll want `get(mean_var)`. I think this question may be a dupe; gonna check.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like a duplicate indeed. I am voting to close.